# Accepting raw HTML in a POST request

Tags: php, html, api, http

I am building an API and I have a method that will accept a POST request with a couple of parameters.

One of the parameters will be HTML code. A user can pass in a whole HTML page, how should I accept this?

Is it ok to ask the user to base64_encode it? Or is it there a better way?

I am worried about parsing invalid characters and different character encodings etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really want the user to encode their HTML with `base64` ?  :)
That would be not viable

Just put a  and accept the HTML. Be careful with XSS and other malicious staff

Comment: What if the html code has an ampersand, this will not effect my POST request?

Comment: @Abs: no........ Here on stackoverflow (and any other website) you put ampersand without any base64 encode by the user :)

Comment: Do you mean the stackoverflow API here: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage - there isn't any post requests or create requests that submit anything?

Comment: @abs: i don't follow what you mean. I am telling you there aren't any poblems with ampersand and other stuff. so dont' be worried.

Comment: With a usual post, values are already either url-encoded or mime-encoded, so the usualy machinism to escape those should be employed, but are often integrated in the library doing the post (i.e.: it is either automatically taken care of by the code on users end, of someone built an HTTP lib from scratch and should know how to escape it, no action required on your part). If you explicitly need _raw_ input, you can just get it with 'file_get_contents("php://input");`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I think using base_64 encoding would be wiser as input. Since while using the API for consumers later on passing in directly the HTML would be prone to injections as well as would get crappy to handle as strings, quotes, special characters etc..

If not then;

A rule could be like you can make another method within your API which wraps the html string like `encode("<html>...</html>")`; this way you would expect the encoded string always and decode it to use further.

Comment: That was my line of thought too. There will always be special characters that I will be dealing with and different languages and character encoding, so if I get the user to base64 encode it, then I can deal with. I am afraid things might get lost in the process.

Comment: Never! nothing could get lost.. Infact base64 encoding is meant to marshal the special characters into ASCII format so they are easily transferable remotely. Same as the case you want it. Relate it with XML somewhat.

Comment: Just to justify a little more; consider the __VIEWSTATE in ASP.NET it is totally encapsulated in base64 encoding beneath which resides the XML for the various controls state key/value pairs.

Comment: base64 encoding IMHO only makes sense in multipart/mime-encoded post, and should work automagically unless you're building a request from scratch. Normally, for HTML the bloat caused by base64-encoding is not needed, for binary files it can be a good idea.